# How to pass UTF-8 string from wx.TextCtrl to wx.ListCtrl

Tags: python, utf-8, wxpython, listctrl, textctrl

If I enter Baltic characters in textctrl and click button **test1** I have an error

```
"InicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: 
                     ordinal not in range(128)"
```

Button **test2** works fine.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, (-1, -1), wx.Size(450, 300))

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.input_area = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1, '',(5,5),(200,200), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.output_list = wx.ListCtrl(self.panel, -1, (210,5), (200,200), style=wx.LC_REPORT)
        self.output_list.InsertColumn(0, 'column')
        self.output_list.SetColumnWidth(0, 100)


        self.btn1 = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, 'test1', (5,220))
        self.btn1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnTest1)

        self.btn2 = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, 'test2', (100,220))
        self.btn2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnTest2)

        self.Centre()

    def OnTest1(self, event):
        self.output_list.InsertStringItem(0,str(self.input_area.GetValue()).decode('utf-8'))

    def OnTest2(self, event):
        self.output_list.InsertStringItem(0,"ąčęėįš".decode('utf-8'))

class MyApp(wx.App):
     def OnInit(self):
         frame = MyFrame(None, -1, 'encoding')
         frame.Show(True)
         return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

### Update 1

I have tried this code on two Windows 7 Ultimate x64 computers.

Both have **python 2.7** and **wxPython2.8 win64 unicode** for python 2.7

In both machines I have the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace
def OnTest1(self, event):
        self.output_list.InsertStringItem(0,str(self.input_area.GetValue()).decode('utf-8'))

with

def OnTest1(self, event):

```
    self.output_list.InsertStringItem(0,self.input_area.GetValue())
```

Answer (score 0):

can't reproduce... If I try with swedish caracters "åäö" it seems to work, also when using "ąčęėįš" locale problem?

Comment: Ubuntu 9.10, Python 2.6.4
In [4]: wx.version() 
Out[4]: '2.8.10.1 (gtk2-unicode)'

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the unicode build of wxPython? You didn't mention your platform and other system details.

Comment: I am useing wxPython2.8-win64-unicode-2.8.11.0-py27 and python-2.7.amd64

Comment: Your sample works for me. GTK -- 2.6.31-22-generic #68-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 26 16:37:17 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux